# How to make a store procedure to create table in Sql server in which name of table will be changed by year e.g Order2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm making a desktop application in C#.Net, and want to make a store procedure in Sql server. It should first check if the table is exists or not if exists it should insert values in the table else create table and table name will taken from the winForm dynamically like in 2019 table should table2019 next this it should create table2020 and so on.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveOrderByYear(@tableName varchar(50),@SaleOrderID    INT,
    @CustomerID     INT,
    @CustomerName   NVARCHAR(100),
    @CustomerNameU  NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleManID      INT,
    @SaleManName    NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleManNameU   NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleExecutiveID        INT,
    @SaleExecutiveName  NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleExecutiveNameU NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleMonth      INT,
    @SaleYear       INT,
    @SaleDate       DATE,
    @SaleTime       TIME(2),
    @CreatedBy      INT,
    @CreatedName    NVARCHAR(100),
    @CreatedNameU   NVARCHAR(100),
    @CreatedDate    DATE) as begin

IF (object_id(@tableName, 'U') is null)
begin declare @query varchar(1000); set @query = 'create table ' + @tableName + ' (SaleOrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                                                                   CustomerID   INT NOT NULL,
                                                                                   CustomerName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   CustomerNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleManID INT NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleManName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleManNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleExecutiveID INT NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleExecutiveName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleExecutiveNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleMonth INT NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleYear  INT NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleDate  DATE NOT NULL,
                                                                                   SaleTime  TIME(2) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   CreatedBy INT NOT NULL,
                                                                                   CreatedName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   CreatedNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                   CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL,
                                                                                   UpdatedBy  INT NULL,
                                                                                   UpdatedName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
                                                                                   UpdatedNameU NVARCHAR(100) NUll,
                                                                                   UpdatedDate DATE NULL
                                                                                    )' exec (@query) end print @query

set @query = 'insert into ' + @tableName + ' (SaleOrderID,CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerNameU,
                SaleManID,SaleManName,SaleManNameU,SaleExecutiveID,SaleExecutiveName,SaleExecutiveNameU,
             SaleMonth,SaleYear,SaleDate,SaleTime,CreatedBy,CreatedName,CreatedNameU,CreatedDate,UpdatedBy,
             UpdatedName,UpdatedNameU,UpdatedDate) values (@SaleOrderID,@CustomerID,@CustomerName,@CustomerNameU,@SaleManID,@SaleManName,@SaleManNameU,@SaleExecutiveID,
    @SaleExecutiveName,@SaleExecutiveNameU,@SaleMonth,@SaleYear,@SaleDate,@SaleTime,@CreatedBy,@CreatedName,
    @CreatedNameU,@CreatedDate)' print @query

exec (@query) end
```

I used this code but it return some errors..
Like

> Incorrect syntax near NVAR  Must Declare scalar variable @SalesOrderID

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: I did nothing yet. I'm confused where to start. Just want to make a store procedure in which table should be created every year with table name and year like order2019, order2020 etc..

Comment: Try googling SQL Server create table - there is plenty of info out there to get you started.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While there's a wealth of information here, this site is not a code writing service. To improve the quality of your Question, please show evidence of what research you have performed into this matter, including links to any pages that have been helpful or sound like they are likely to be related. Please show us any code you have tried and a description of the results you have received (including the full text of any error messages). [Look here for tips on writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have modified the question and showed what i have tried and errors its returns.

Comment: Creating different tables by year is a **very bad design**, you should create only 1 table with a date parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement in SQL server using a dynamic query (execute statement). You need to build a query in SQL stored procedure dynamically, either you can pass the table name as a parameter or you can build the table name inside the stored procedure itself. below is the sample code to achieve your requirement. The stored procedure taking table name as a parameter and checking if the table does not already exist then will create the table and thereafter insert the data in that table. this is just a sample to demonstrate how this feature can be built. You can modify it further the table structure and the insert statement based on data which you need to insert. Please feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

### Sample code

create procedure Proc1(@tableName varchar(50))
as
begin

IF (object_id(@tableName, 'U') is null)
begin
declare @query varchar(1000);
set @query = 'create table '  +  @tableName + 
' (field1 varchar(100) )'
exec (@query)
end
print @query

set @query = 'insert into ' +  @tableName  + 
' (field1) values  (''test data'')'
print @query

exec (@query)
end

-- exec Proc1 'order2020'

Comment: I used this code it runs but when i modify it gives some errors read my question just edited for detail. And Please suggest me how to solve those errors.

Comment: You need to concatenate other parameters also in the insert statement as did for @tablename variable

Answer (score 0):

We can fix your SP to make it work, but I'll focus on the wrong approach I noticed you are trying to use, which is *creating different versions of the same table with it's year in it's name*. This is a very bad design for several reasons (maintenance, performance, simplicity of querying, etc.).

What you should enforce instead is to create only 1 table with a `DATE` (or `DATETIME`) column, then query each year/month depending on your needs.

```
CREATE TABLE SaleOrder (
    SaleOrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID   INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CustomerNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SaleManID INT NOT NULL,
    SaleManName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SaleManNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SaleExecutiveID INT NOT NULL,
    SaleExecutiveName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SaleExecutiveNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SaleMonth INT NOT NULL,
    SaleYear  INT NOT NULL,
    SaleDate  DATE NOT NULL,
    SaleTime  TIME(2) NOT NULL,
    CreatedBy INT NOT NULL,
    CreatedName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CreatedNameU NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL,
    UpdatedBy  INT NULL,
    UpdatedName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    UpdatedNameU NVARCHAR(100) NUll,
    UpdatedDate DATE NULL,

    SaleOrderDate DATE) -- We will use this new column as example
```

So this:

```
SELECT S.* FROM SaleOrder2018 AS S
```

becomes this:

```
SELECT S.* FROM SaleOrder AS S WHERE YEAR(S.SaleOrderDate) = 2018
```

If when inserting you don't know which date it should be completed with, you could infer from one of your other date columns:

```
INSERT INTO SaleOrder (
    /*All Column List*/
    SaleOrderDate)
SELECT (
    /*All Column List*/
    SaleOrderDate = @CreatedDate -- Or @UpdatedDate, or any expression you can use to know the proper date
```

If you might have repeated "primary keys" for `SaleOrderID` column amongst different years, you can use an auto-generated, no-business related value as `PRIMARY KEY` (which is very common to use). You can do this declaring a column as `IDENTITY`:

```
CREATE TABLE SaleOrder (
    SaleOrderAutoID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SaleOrderID INT NOT NULL -- remove PRIMARY KEY from this one
    /*... other columns*/
    )
```

Using this you don't have to check for the existence of the table before inserting, and your SP directly inserts the data without the need of Dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveOrder(
    @SaleOrderID    INT,
    @CustomerID     INT,
    @CustomerName   NVARCHAR(100),
    @CustomerNameU  NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleManID      INT,
    @SaleManName    NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleManNameU   NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleExecutiveID        INT,
    @SaleExecutiveName  NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleExecutiveNameU NVARCHAR(100),
    @SaleMonth      INT,
    @SaleYear       INT,
    @SaleDate       DATE,
    @SaleTime       TIME(2),
    @CreatedBy      INT,
    @CreatedName    NVARCHAR(100),
    @CreatedNameU   NVARCHAR(100),
    @CreatedDate    DATE) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SaleOrder (
        SaleOrderID,
        CustomerID,
        CustomerName,
        CustomerNameU,
        SaleManID,
        SaleManName,
        SaleManNameU,
        SaleExecutiveID,
        SaleExecutiveName,
        SaleExecutiveNameU,
        SaleMonth,
        SaleYear,
        SaleDate,
        SaleTime,
        CreatedBy,
        CreatedName ,
        CreatedNameU,
        CreatedDate,
        --UpdatedBy,
        --UpdatedName,
        --UpdatedNameU,
        --UpdatedDate,
        SaleOrderDate)
    SELECT
        SaleOrderID = @SaleOrderID,
        CustomerID = @CustomerID,
        CustomerName = @CustomerName,
        CustomerNameU = @CustomerNameU,
        SaleManID = @SaleManID,
        SaleManName = @SaleManName,
        SaleManNameU = @SaleManNameU,
        SaleExecutiveID = @SaleExecutiveID,
        SaleExecutiveName = @SaleExecutiveName,
        SaleExecutiveNameU = @SaleExecutiveNameU,
        SaleMonth = @SaleMonth,
        SaleYear = @SaleYear,
        SaleDate = @SaleDate,
        SaleTime = @SaleTime,
        CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,
        CreatedName = @CreatedName,
        CreatedNameU = @CreatedNameU,
        CreatedDate = @CreatedDate,
        --UpdatedBy = ,
        --UpdatedName,
        --UpdatedNameU,
        --UpdatedDate,
        SaleOrderDate = @SaleDate

END
```